# How to develop professional looking UI form winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, qt, user-interface, sdk

I have created a winforms application with C# application. The main purpose of the application is to scan the registry, fix the errors and display the report. And of course few other works as Task Scheduling, Disk Defragmenting etc.

There are 4 tabs
1. Home (functionalities can be selected from here).
2. Update (Update the product)
3. History ( all the history are noted here)
4. Settings and Configuration (basic settings of applications)

I have completed the whole application, and UI is of very basic lever where I'm using tabs.  From [KRB Tab](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38014/KRBTabControl)  and doing some modifications as per my requirement.

However still the UI doesnt seem too professional.

I would like to do something like

Bit Defender
 [image: BitDefender] or

CC Cleaner or

At least like SQLite Manager [image: SQlite Manager].

Any suggestions on how I can achieve these would be really appreciated.

I have heard that Utilities like McAfee whose UI are very professional uses [QT](http://qt-project.org/) . I have also heard of [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com)  which have some reviews about UI development.

I would still like to know what I have to do in order to make professional looking application.

Some suggested me to go about developing in WPF but that will take me another few more months for the completion. Anything that remains to winforms will be really appreciated. Also I'm looking for something free to use. However if there isnt any I can go with any paid SDK's

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If you seriously think of the Qt framework, then I just can't see how you can discount WPF. You will have to port your code either way. My personal preference would be to use Qt Quick 2 with Qt, but WPF offers similar functionality, done very differently of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're using [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/). [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx) is popular as well. Both frameworks are highly professional, skinable, ...

Comment: I use DevExpress too,and it is nice . But unfortunately is not free, and not cheap at all.

Comment: I agree, but the question has "professional" in its title. Professional doesn't come for free.

Comment: Yeah I did fair amount of research on both of them, they do look good however they are not cheap. Rates go somewhere around $999 which really is not in my budget level. Anything else?

Any other alternatives?

Comment: I have also heard about HTML rendering with winforms(although not so sure about it) where  one can render JQuery/Javascript as well as Html and Css to the winforms. Just an eavesdrop though.